# Is there any way to remove multiple forms from a VB6 project?

Tags: forms, vb6

I have a VB6 project with over 300 forms.  I want to remove all but 30 forms but I want to be able to remove more than one form at a time.  I would like to be able to select the 270 forms that I want to remove and then just click a button.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From inside the IDE it is not possible.
But the project file is just a plain textfile.

Open it in an editor of your choice and simply remove the lines you don't need.

Forms look like this:

```
Form=frmProcess.frm
```